# AddOpenIdConnect with an External Configuration Service

Tags: c#, .net-core, openid, asp.net-core-3.1

I am adding OpenIdConnect to my app like so:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
     var clientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("clientSecret");
     options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
});
```

I'd like to be able to use another service to get the secret like this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", (services, options) =>
{
    var secretService = services.GetService<ISecretService>();
    var clientSecret = secretService.Get("clientSecret");
    options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
});
```

I saw there is use of `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` but I don't see it in the nuget package.

I have the following installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.1.0" />
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you keep secrets?

Comment: Either Azure or AWS. Local dotnet secrets for dev

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to execute a post configuration class that can inject services.
Like so:

```
public class OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    private readonly ISecretsService _secretsService;

    public OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions(ISecretsService secretsService)
    {
        _secretsService = secretsService;
    }

    public async void PostConfigure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.ClientSecret = await _secretsService.Get("clientSecret");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the described case I'd recommend extending Configuration rather than using DI in the Action.**

To access secrets you can add Configuration providers and continue to use Configuration.GetValue in ConfigureServices method.

For Azure Key-Vault it is under [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/) nuget package.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            if (env.IsLocal())
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultUri);
            }
        })
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

For AWS - [Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager/)

Comment: This answer is not related to OpenIdConnect. It just generally just implies how to get use Secret Management but not how to use them in OpenIdConnect

Comment: I mean in the described case I would not go with injecting service but with extending Configuration

Comment: Well the problem is that AddOpenConnectId doesn't give you a IServiceProvider. Your solution doesn't provide a way to configure this situation. I also understand I should extend the configuration but I didn't realize this when I wrote the question. In short, if I use your solution it won't help me at all